# Pipe command output to Reader through gzip

Tags: go

I'm trying to execute a shell command and compress it's output.
The problem is that I then need to interface with an API that expects a Reader.

For that I tried with the following (simplified code):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "testing"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os/exec"
    "compress/gzip"
)

func TestPipe(t *testing.T) {
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello_from_echo")

    reader, writer := io.Pipe()
    gzW := gzip.NewWriter(writer)

    cmd.Stdout = gzW 
    cmd.Start()

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Waiting")
        cmd.Wait()
        fmt.Println("wait done")
        // writer.Close()
        // gzW.Close()
    }()

    msg, _ := ioutil.ReadAll( reader )
    fmt.Println( hex.EncodeToString( msg ) )
}
```

The problem is that ReadAll hangs forever. If I close `gzW` nothing really changes. However, if I close the `writer` variable, now the program finishes without hanging, but the output is:

```
$ go test -run Pipe
Waiting
wait done
1f8b080000096e8800ff
PASS
```

However, no matter what I echo the output is the same. If I try it from the command line like this: `echo "hello_from_echo" | gzip | hexdump` the output is totally different, so there's something wrong with that approach.

Any clue what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're closing the gzip writer and pipe writer in the wrong order. You need to close the `gzip.Writer` to flush any buffers and write the gzip footer, then you can close the `PipeWriter` to unblock the `ReadAll`. Also adding the `WaitGroup` ensures that you're not blocked on any of the close calls.

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello_from_echo and more")

pr, pw := io.Pipe()
gzW := gzip.NewWriter(pw)

cmd.Stdout = gzW
cmd.Start()

var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    err := cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    gzW.Close()
    pw.Close()
}()

buf, err := ioutil.ReadAll(pr)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
wg.Wait()
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(buf))
```

Comment: Doesn't cmd.Wait close the output ? (that is the gzW)
For now I solved by manually calling flush on the gzW, but will try your solution and report back

Comment: @FerminSilva, no it does not call Close. (Cmd.Stdout is an `io.Writer`, not an `io.WriteCloser`). Also, if you don't Close the `gzip.Writer`, the crc footer won't be written, and decompressing the output will error.

Comment: good to know! BTW, whats the problem about blocking on the close calls if my code is already in a gorutine?

Comment: @FerminSilva: Blocking in the goroutine is fine, but in this case if one of those calls is blocking, it's because of a problem. With the added `WaitGroup`, if you close the pipe first you'll see that the goroutine doesn't return because the `gzip.Writer` can't close.

Comment: Great. Last question, can I assume (with _some_ confidence) that if a library requires a Writer then I will need to call close myself but if a library requires a WriterCloser then it will close the stream when it's done ?

Comment: @FerminSilva: I would say that's a good general assumption, as functions should ask for the minimal interface needed, but having documentation that confirms the behavior is always better.